# Magento2 Hiding static-block in checkout pages

Tags: magento2, static-block

I edited this file `[vendor]/[theme name]/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml` and use this code to hide the static block:

```
<referenceContainer>
<block name="custom.block.header" remove="true"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

The error output was something along the lines :

> Element with ID'custom.block.header' already exists

What am I doing wrong here?

this is the full code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="empty" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
<move element="logo" destination="porto_header" />
<referenceBlock name="custom.block.header" remove="true"/>
</body>
</page>
```

Comment: Please share your xml file full code

Answer (score 0):

This is how we remove a block in magento 2

```
<referenceBlock name="custom.block.header" remove="true"/>
```

full eg.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="footer_links" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

I would highly suggest, not to make changes in core files, create/extend default theme and make changes there.

Comment: I tried this, the error is gone but the block is still there, even after I did cache clearing . I am extending the file i custom theme.

Comment: what do you want to remove exactly.

Comment: a static-block in checkout page, i extend the file in this path Theme Vendor /Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.phtml

Comment: I think you are doing something wrong there can not be a phtml file in layout folder. it should be /Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

Comment: this is the file you should be making changes to `<MagentoRoot>/app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<ThemeName>/Magento_Checkout\layout\checkout_index_index.xml`

Comment: i made a mistake, that is the exact path that I'm extending the XML in

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46913/discussion-between-ree-and-arun-karnawat).